# Unbinding click and mouseover events during animation

Tags: jquery, html

How do I unbind click and mouseover events until animations complete and bind them afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the animation starts use these:

```
$('#foo').unbind();              //unbinds all
$('#foo').unbind('click');       //only click event
$('#foo').unbind('mouseover');   //only mouseover event
```

and then bind the events when it completes...

here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YmJzt/2/

the basics from the fiddle are:

```
function aClick() { alert("YAY! I'm working") }

$("#animateBtn").click(function () {
    //First Unbind
    $("#theone").unbind('click', aClick).text("Does nothing...");

    //Then Animate
    $("#block").animate({
        width: "70%",
        opacity: 0.4,
        marginLeft: "0.6in",
        fontSize: "3em",
        borderWidth: "10px"
    }, 1500,
    //On animation complete bind back... 
    function () {$("#theone").click(aClick).text("Can Click!");}
   );
});
```

Comment: its not a safe suloution becouse in case of more than one event handler subscribing to an event it will unbind them all, its better to send the specific event handler function to unbind as the secound arg.

Comment: @AhmadF see my fiddle example you can selectively define which function you want to unbind....

Comment: NOW your soultion is good!

Comment: Thanks Mortalus it helped me:) Sorry am unable to upvote your answer because i dont have enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

if you want to disable links for a period of time its both easier and faster to use classes. look at below:

```
$('link').click(function(event){
  if(event.hasClass('disabled'))
    return;
  else{
    event.animate(/*some args*/ , function(){   // call back function
      event.removeClass('disabled');
    });
  }
});
```

you just need to add a css for `.disabled` inorder to disable the links!

this piece of code is faster than using unbind becouse it has no overhead.

Answer (score 0):

see [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

u can unbind event like

```
$("p").unbind("click,mouseover");
```

for remove until animation complete

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
     $("p").unbind("click,mouseover");// herer unbind done  
  });

$("p").bind("click,mouseover");// here bind again  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickme').unbind('click').unbind('mouseover');
$( "#book" ).animate({
            opacity: 0.25,
            left: "+=50",
            height: "toggle"
        }, 5000, function() {
             $('#clickme').bind('click', click_function).bind('mouseover', mouseover_function)
        });  
$( "#clickme" ).click(click_function);
function click_function(){
     //do something
}
function mouseover_function(){
     //do something
}
```

this will unbind click from the element just before the animation and rebind it in the callback on complete of the animation

Answer (score 0):

Don't unbind the event handlers. Just set a flag when the animation is on and reset it when done. Now in those event handlers, check if that flag is set and return false if yes else let the handler execute.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `is(:animated)` to check if an animation is running currently.

```
$('element').click(function(){

     if($(this).is(':animated')){

         // the element is currently animated

     }else{

         // the element is not being animated

     }

})
```

If you are looking to stop the current running animation you can use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). Using `stop(true, true)`, stops if an animation is running currently on an element, and jumps to the end.

Comment: I think the he/she wants to prevent `click` and `mouseover` events from triggering on the element during the animation, not stop the animation. Then again, the question isn't worded well.